# I want to calculate the pixel values of an image and export to a standard format

Tags: image-processing

After finishing a few tutorials, I thought I was ready to calculate the pixel values of a large (smaller numbers 20x20 used here) image and export to a standard format (.jpg) but my code doesn't work. I am clearly missing something important. I thought it might be best to see if someone would look at a small segment of the code and comment.

```
(* image calc *)
numrow = 20;
numcol = 20;

(* midpoint of image *)
midrow = N[numrow/2];
midcol = N[numcol/2];

(* azimuth angle of pixel from center point *) 
(* mixed symbolic and numeric results *)
patfun[i_,j_] := N[ArcTan[i-midrow,j-midcol]];

(* spoke-like image *)
pat = Array[patfun[i,j], 20, 20];
```

Comment: This is just the simple stuff... you haven't yet shown where you're going wrong and how you failed at exporting.

Comment: There is another tutorial you should read: [common pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/3066)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it, which keeps the auxiliary variables localized.

```
pixelData =
  With[{numrow = 200, numcol = 200}, 
    With[{midrow = numrow/2, midcol = numcol/2},
      Block[{patfun},
        patfun[midrow, midcol] = 0.; 
        patfun[i_, j_] := N[ArcTan[i - midrow, j - midcol]];
        Table[patfun[i, j], {i, 0, numrow}, {j, 0, numcol}]]]];
img = Image @ Rescale @ pixelData
```

[image: image.png]

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way: Especially for listable built in functions like `ArcTan` using (packed) arrays for coordinates might be faster than calling ArcTan for every single pixel.

```
dim={20,20};
x=Array[#1&,dim,{{-1.,1.},{-1.,1.}}];
y=Array[#2&,dim,{{-1.,1.},{-1.,1.}}];
img=Image[Rescale[ArcTan[x,y]]]
```

[image]

```
Export["filename here",img];
```

(And to prevent the division by zero at x/y=0, if the dimensions aren't even, I usually just cheat and add a small number like 10^-10 or `$MachineEpsilon` to `x` or `y`.)

Answer (score 3):

To supplement the other answers: by adding a semicolon at the end of every line, you sometimes don't spot the errors soon enough. For example, after:

```
pat = Array[patfun[i, j], {20, 20}]
```

you would have seen a list of

```
{{ArcTan[-10. + i, -10. + j][1, 1], ...
```

where the `i` and `j` are hanging around like uninvited guests.

After 'correcting' this line to:

```
pat = Array[patfun, {20, 20}]
```

you see an error message:

```
ArcTan::indet: Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0.,0.] encountered. >>
```

and, halfway down (if you've left the semicolon off):

```
{-1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708,
 -1.5708, Indeterminate, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708,
 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708},
```

and that `Indeterminate` will frustrate a subsequent attempt to apply the `Image` function to your data. You could, I suppose, do this:

```
Image[pat /. Indeterminate -> 0]
```

but I think the other solutions here - avoiding errors rather than cleaning up after them - are better.

Comment: +1, but don't do this for images from a typical megapixel camera. I regularly loose hours of unsaved work by doing just that...

Answer (score 2):

Several coding problems addressed. Take a look:

```
hNumrow = hNumcol = 10;
patfun[i_, j_] := If[i - hNumrow == 0, Pi/2 Sign[j - hNumcol], ArcTan[i - hNumrow, j - hNumcol]];
pat = Rescale@Array[patfun[#1, #2] &, 2 {hNumrow, hNumcol}];
Image@pat
Export["\\yourFile.jpg", Image@pat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]